# Positioning image on bottom right behind an svg element

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to position an image behind an angled SVG separator. This is what we would like it to look like:

[image]

As you can see, the Toucan is cut off by the angled SVG triangle so that it looks like the character is behind the page... unfortunately this is what it looks like at the moment:

[image]

Here is my current html structure:

```
<!-- hero -->
<div class="container-fluid bg-hero padding-angled-medium">
    <div class="container">

        <h1>Learn <span>English</span></h1>
        <h2>with someone perfect for you</h2>
        <h4>Professional one-to-one English lessons with teachers who care</h4>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <a class="btn btn-hero center-block" href="<?php echo base_url('book/free'); ?>">Free Evaluation</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <a class="btn btn-secondary-cta default center-block" href="<?php echo base_url('courses'); ?>">View Courses</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img id="toucan" class="img-responsive pull-right" src="<?php echo base_url('Public/images/frontend/home/toucan.png'); ?>" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<!-- end hero -->

<!-- white angled svg -->
<svg class="angled-div" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 10" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <polygon points="100 0 100 10.1 0 10.1" fill="white"/>
</svg>
<!-- end white angled svg -->
```

Just incase here is my SASS code that styles the page:

```
// hero
.bg-hero {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#4d000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    width:100%;
    h1 {
        font-size: $font-largest;
        font-weight: 800;
        span {
            color: $brand;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            text-decoration: underline;
            text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
        }
    }
    h4 {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    /* Custom, iPhone Retina */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
        #toucan {
            margin-top: 0px;
        }
    }

    /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
        #toucan {
            margin-top: 0px;
        }
    }

    /* Small Devices, Tablets */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
        #toucan {
            margin-top: 0px;
        }
    }

    /* Medium Devices, Desktops */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
        #toucan {
            margin-top: -100px;
            margin-bottom: -150px;
        }
    }

    /* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
        #toucan {
            margin-top: -100px;
            margin-bottom: -150px;
        }
    }
}
```

Qusetion: is there a css trick to get the image behind the SVG? Or do I need to work a new HTML structure to get the desired effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend giving the image in your css the [z - index css property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) And maybe giving it a negative z - index, such as: `#yourImage {z - index: -1;}`, also keep in mind that you should give the SVG separator a greater z - index than the image so that it is positioned in front of it. Warning: this may mess up the other z - index elements on the page.

Comment: Thanks! Works great.